# Particle system domain box deforms the character (smoke effect)

Tags: animation, particles

I've been trying to create an animation for a creature where he slams the ground and there' s shockwave effect right after the animation.

However, I moved the domain box, where the smoke effect takes place right under the creature that slams the ground and it suddenly deformed the creature (so the creature fitted right in the domain box somehow).

The domain box seems to have animations saved somehow. Maybe this might cause the problem.[image]

I am not sure what causes it.

Comment: I will include the .blend file soon. Blend exchange is bugging for some odd reasons for me. Can' t upload the file..

Comment: What's wrong with Blend Exchange. Can' t upload anything there.

Comment: Ahh.. here' s the .blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37646

Comment: I heard that Blend-Exchange is giving trouble! Any details?

Comment: Not sure. It just didn' t upload  the file.. So I used pastall instead.. 
I tried to upload the file for half an hour, it still didn' t do anything. It seems strange though..

Comment: Did you enter the url of the question?

Comment: Also can you check in the javascript console for any errors?

Comment: I did enter the url of the question. However, I don't use firefox myself to have firebug and check for javascript errors.. Don't know...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27190/discussion-between-giantcowfilms-and-thelast-blenderbender).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rig object has a non-uniform scale, giving the character a squished appearance.

To fix this, clear the keyframes on the scale (as the scale doesn't actually change, this won't affect the appearance of the animation), then copy the X or Y value to the Z value:

[image]

This shouldn't have been caused or otherwise had anything to do with the smoke simulation. Perhaps you may have accidentally changed the scale while [*Auto keyframe*](http://blender.org/manual/animation/basics/actions.html#auto-keyframe) was enabled (as it is in your screenshot)?

Comment: If you use the particle system yourself, has Blender crashed?
I can' t understand whether it's my computer or some bugs in the particle systems that cause crash when I try to do something with it.

Comment: @TheLast_BlenderBender It's working fine for me.. Is it possible you are running out of memory?

Comment: Yep. Might be. Need to get something better for doing stuff like this :)